# How to include jquery and datatables through <script> tag in electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, electron

I want to include datatables.net inside my electron app. I did not find a way to include the jquery through a `<script>` tag. When I install it through npm it fails

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'datatables.net-dt'

var $       = require( 'jquery' );
var dt      = require( 'datatables.net-dt' )();
//var buttons = require( 'datatables.net-buttons-dt' )();
$(document).ready(function(){alert("ready")});
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const Menu = remote.Menu;
const MenuItem = remote.MenuItem;
const dialog = remote.require('dialog');
const fs = require('fs');
const parser = require('babyparse');

var template = [
{
label: 'File',
submenu: [
  {
    label: 'Open',
    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O',
    role: 'open',
    click:function(){openFile()}
  }
]
}
]
var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

  function openFile () {
   dialog.showOpenDialog({ filters: [
   { name: 'text', extensions: ['txt'] },
   {name:'csv', extensions:['csv']}
  ]}, function (fileNames) {
  if (fileNames === undefined) return;
   var fileName = fileNames[0];
  fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
  // console.log(data);
   var elem = document.getElementById("data");
  elem.innerHTML= data;
  parser.parse(data,{complete:function(results){
var json = JSON.stringify(results.data);
var elem = document.getElementById("data");
elem.innerHTML= json;
//console.log(results.data)
 }})
});
  }); 
  }
```

This is the code inside index.html
Is this achievable? What happens with javascript libraries which are not provided as modules? How to use them inside electron?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/faq/electron-faq.md#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron) you've got a couple of options:

- Switch off Node integration in the Electron `BrowserWindow`.
- Hide the fact that Node integration is switched on by removing `require`, `exports`, and `module` properties from the `window` object.

When you install jQuery via NPM you can also `require` it like this in your `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <script>
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
  </script>
</head>
```

Note that the above snippet assumes the following directory structure:

```
node_modules/
  jquery/
index.html
```

Comment: If I switch of the node integration, I am loosing file dialogs access to filesystem and other useful functionality that I need.

Comment: The second option would've suited you then, but you'd have to remove `require`, `exports`, `module` from `window`, load jQuery and then add back the removed properties to `window`. In this particular case I think it's easier to just `require` jQuery, so I've expanded my original answer to show how you'd do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ll give it a try and will come back if I have questions